# sqlalchemy attribute is tuple after assignment

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy 1.0.12. When I have an instance of my model & assign a new value to an attribute, I get a `tuple` instead of the value.

```
type(self.address1)
<class 'tuple'>
```

This wreaks a bit of havoc when I try to use `marshmallow-sqlalchemy` 0.8.1 to do a `dump`:

```
SomeSchema().dump(self).data
```

The assigned basically doesn't show up in the dumped data because it doesn't know how to marshal a `tuple`. The only way to "flatten" the tuple/attributes is to do a `session.commit()` before doing a `dump()`.

Is there a cleaner way? I have other instances to change/create before I want to do a `session.commit()`.

Comment: Could you add an MCVE? That sounds pretty odd behaviour and I'm somewhat sure, that you have an erroneous comma in your assignment statement (hence the tuple).

Comment: Whoa! Good call! You're right. Chalk it up to bad copy & paste. Thanks!

Comment: Arrrgh.. why is this a valid tuple? `a = 1,`

Comment: Thank you so much for asking this question. I came across the same issue and it was exactly the same reason: `injection.length_mm = dlg.length_mm,` wracks the whole thing. This should never be a Tuple but raise an exception instead...arghh

Comment: I second @MrLeeh.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a user error. I accidentally had a comma at the end of an assignment, and python created a tuple as the return value.

This returns an integer

```
1
```

This returns a tuple

```
1,
```

Removing the comma in my `return` statement as suggested in the comments by [Ilja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%C3%A4) worked